# jQuery validation plugin, required if .is(":checked")

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to get the jQuery validation plugin to set a text type input to required when a radio.is(":checked")... I know the following code works, on jsFiddle..., but it doesn't work from within the intranet where I work... Is there an alternative to the following?:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            t1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            t2: {
                required: function (element) {
                  if($('#rad2').is(":checked"))
                    {
                      return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      return false;
                    }
                },
                minlength:5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            t1: {
                required: "Enter t1",
                minlength: "min is 5"
            },
            t2: {
        required: "Required t2",
                minlength: "min is 5"
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<label><input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radio">Rad 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" id="rad2" name="radio">Rad 2</label>
<input type="text" name="t1" maxlength="10">
<input type="text" name="t2" maxlength="10">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I can't seem to get the function from within the required clause to operate.. I receive no errors or anything.. just doesn't work.. I've also tried:

```js
required: $('#rad1').is(":checked")
```

as I believe that would give me just a simple true/false.. also didn't work. I may be out of luck but the rest of the validation plugin works so thought there may be another way.

Comment: You should consider to not write your custom rule there. Use the .addMethod(). It´s more readable and easier to test

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a jQuery verson > 1.6, the correct way to go is:

```
if ($("#rad2").prop("checked", true))
  return true;
return false;
```

If the jQuery version is 1.6 or less:

```
if ($("#rad2").attr("checked", "checked"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding to my question... I did find a solution, I don't exactly understand it but it may just have to do with how my company's infrastructure is setup... I ended up making a variable before the validation function:

```js
var ths = this;
```

and used that to select my radio button. For some reason trying to select through normal means wasn't working. Sorry for this silly question but I greatly appreciate the help.

Thank you